# Using a pointer to function pointers without typedef?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I am trying to use a collection of function pointers of type `double* (*func)(double*, double)` of length determined at runtime.  I can do this using `typedef` by

```
typedef double* (*func)(double*, double);

...

func* functions = new func[5];
```

I understand that `typedef` is the 'correct' way to do this but I am wondering if there is a way to do this without using `typedef`.  All the information I have been able find on this type of thing only uses arryays of function pointers not pointers to function pointers.  I think the decalration

```
double* (**functions)(double*, double);
```

would be correct but I can't seem to figure out how to initialize such a thing using `new`.

Comment: (oh and also, **why would you ever do this?**)

Comment: `template<typename T> void make_error( T&& t ) { static_assert(false, "an error" ); }` will often dump out the name of the function, including the type of `T`, when called with a variable.  Build your type using `typedef`, then call `make_error`, and examine the error output.  Without `static_assert`, nearly any silly error works.

Comment: @Ryan I just like the simplicity that the typedef brings.

Comment: If you use C++ then you should be using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: If you want to do this to enhance your understanding of the language syntax, that's good food for thought. If you're thinking to gain some advantage from using that in your code ... well, good luck! After all, some people like puzzle games! ;-)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - seems to me that `std::function` is overkill here. It's useful when you need to use callable objects (including functions) whose argument and return types do not match the way they'll be called. `std::function` makes the conversions needed for the call transparent, but that introduces overhead which isn't needed when all the functions have the same type and that's what's being called, which is the case here.

Comment: Use the typedef, and, as @JoachimPileborg suggests, use `std::vector`. It will save a great deal of time and a great deal of mental pain.

Comment: _For the fun only:_ `double* (**functions)(double*, double) = new (double* (* [5])(double*, double));` seems correct. **Don't do that.**

Comment: It's going to the dark side, good question though.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know it is quite disgusting but I am writing a program to do numeric solutions to a system of ODEs and would like it to handle arbitrary dimensional systems hence the need for a collection of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double *(**functions)(double *, double) = new (double *(*[5])(double *, double));
```

to use an abstract function type (or pointer to function) in a `new` expression, you need to put the abstract type in parenthesis -- from 5.3.4 of the C++ spec:

> *new-expression:* 
>
>           **::***<sub>opt</sub>* **new** *new-placement<sub>opt</sub> new-type-id new-initializer<sub>opt</sub>* 
>
>           **::***<sub>opt</sub>* **new** *new-placement<sub>opt</sub>* **(** *type-id* **)** *new-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*

a *new-type-id* cannot express function types.

Knowing the details of the C++ grammar specification is useful if you're trying to generate (or obfuscate) code automatically, but for real code that you expect humans to read, you should just use the typedef.

Comment: **Disclaimer:** Never _actually_ write code like that. (Please.)

Comment: That works.  I could swear I had tried this a few times but alas I must have forgotten the outermost parenthesizes.  I am of course using a typedef, but the knowledge of how to do it directly couldn't hurt. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<double*(*)(double*, double)> function_table;
```

But putting aside artificial constraints:

```
typedef double *(*f_ptr)(double*, double);
std::vector<f_ptr> function_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is given in one of the comments:

```
double *(**fns)(double *, double)
```

would declare a pointer to pointer to function returning a `double *`, with the arguments a `double *` and a `double`.

However, it's quite hard to read even before it became a pointer to pointer, so I'm not convinced you'd want to do this just to save a little bit of typing... (`typedef` and a name).

Of course, since this is C++, using

```
std::vector<std::function<double *(double *, double)>> fns;
```

would be the "right" thing to do, or perhaps even

```
std::vector<std::function<std::vector<double>(std::vector<double>, double)>> fns;`
```

Comment: There's no need here for the internal argument conversions that `std::function` does. Just create a vector of function pointers.

Answer (score -1):

- Are you getting an error message if you try to initialize the variable functions? If so then you need to cast the initialization to.
- func* functions = (func *) new func[5];

Comment: No. `new X` and `new X[N]` already return a properly typed pointer of type `X*`.